# How to position a D3 path on a canvas using the moveTo function?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js, geojson

I'm using D3.js to parse some geoJson files and display them on a canvas. However, i'm struggling to position them using the moveTo() function id expect to use when working with an HTML5 canvas.

The [D3 docs say](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path_context):

> ## path.context([context])
>
> If context is specified, sets the render context and returns the path
>   generator. If the context is null, then the path generator will return
>   an SVG path string when invoked on a given feature. If the context is
>   non-null, the path generator will instead call methods on the
>   specified context to render geometry. The context must implement the
>   following methods:
>
> beginPath()
>   moveTo(x, y)
>   lineTo(x, y)
>   arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle)
>   closePath()
>
> Note that this is a subset of the canvas
>   element’s 2D rendering context, and thus a canvas context can be
>   passed to the path generator, in which case geometry will be rendered
>   directly to the canvas. If context is not specified, returns the
>   current render context, which defaults to null.

So i understand i can pass the context of the canvas to `path`, but i've not had any success to date - my output always sits at `0,0`.

My code is as follows:

```
var files = ["file-a.geojson", "file-b.geojson", "file-c.gpx.geojson"];

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
        .attr("style", "outline: thin solid red;")
        .attr("width", "1052")
        .attr("height", "1488");

    var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

    var routeWidth = 105,
        routeHeight = 105;

    for (var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
      d3.json("example-data/"+files[i], function(error, data) {

        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .scale(1)
            .translate([0, 0]);

        var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

        var b = path.bounds(data),
            s = 0.95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / routeWidth, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / routeHeight),
            t = [(routeWidth - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (routeHeight - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

        projection
          .scale(s)
          .translate(t);

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(300, 300);
        path.context(context)(data);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
      });
    };
```

So my question is, how do i position each `path` on my canvas as i iterate over them?

Comment: The way to do this is to have several `canvas` elements that are positioned appropriately. The D3 path generator starts a new path when you call it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I wasn't aware i could 'stitch' multiple canvas elements together. This is the approach i've taken. If you'd like to add your suggestion as an answer, i'd happily mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The D3 canvas path generator starts a new path when it is called, so there's no easy way to offset the starting position. However, you can multiple, overlapping `canvas` elements that you can position appropriately. That way, each path starts where you want it to start.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling context.moveTo(300, 300) inside your loop, call context.translate(300, 300) before the loop.